# What is the shortcut combination to create a non-breaking space using the keyboard ISO International layout on Debian?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

What is the `shortcut combination` to create a `non-breaking space` using the keyboard `US ISO International` layout on `Debian 10`?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't part of the base layout, but can be enabled as an option across all layouts:

```
setxkbmap -option nbsp:level3
```

- Option **`nbsp:level3`** will bind <kbd>AltGr</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>.
- Option `nbsp:level4` should bind <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>AltGr</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>
- Option `nbsp:level2` should bind <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>. This results in *a lot* of typos.

If you use GNOME, you can find this option in *gnome-tweaks* under "Keyboard & Mouse" → "Advanced Layout Options":

[image]

Comment: How can I set it permanently from command line? I use cinnamon, do you know how I can do manually with cinnamon?